# How would you write a SystemVerilog Function that adds an even parity bit to a 7-bit vector?

Tags: system-verilog, digital-logic

Would you take a 7-bit logic variable as an input and return an 8-bit logic output with the parity bit being the MSB (leftmost bit) of the output?
In a system that uses even parity you want the total number of 1 bits in the output vector to be even, right?
Can the the unary ^ operator can be used to calculate even parity?

Trying to figure out what that would look like?

I started something like this:

[Code for parity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o9SI.png)

Sorry if this is more than one question.

Comment: Please show us what you tried. We will not do your homework for you. We can give hints and address specific challenges.

Comment: Ok, I did an edit to show you the parity part I have so far, but I wouldn't know how to add an even parity bit with that bit being the MSB? Just suggestions or hints will be good to know.

Comment: Hint: search for “Verilog concatenation”. FYI, it’s better to post the actual code then a screenshot

Comment: yes, `^` can be used to check parity. Also look at the reduction `^` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this like this:

```
input logic [N-1:0] data_in;
output logic [N:0] data_out;

assign data_out = {^data_in, data_in};
```

The `^` reduction operator does an XOR operation on all the bits in the operand. (So, it will return '1 if `data_in` has an odd number of ones.)